# How to integrate Laravel app with Azure Monitor Logs

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have Laravel application runs on an azure VM and  I would like to send app logs to Azure Monitoring Logs instead of use the traditional log file.

I have checked this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs but it also depends on custom log file.

Is there any other solutions to send logs directly to azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For monitoring application data, we use azure application insights service. However, currently the instrumentation is available only few languages as stated
  in this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/platforms#unsupported-community-sdks)
- Alternatively, you can use [Open Telemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/php/) in PHP which is a observability framework – an API, SDK, and tools that are designed to aid in the generation and collection of application telemetry data such as metrics, logs, and traces **which is not currently in production**.
- You can also leverage the below SDK to write your custom log messages to application insights.
  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP

https://github.com/provisions-group/ms-application-insights-laravel

Comment: Thanks a lot, currently i am using custom logs to integrate my app with azure monitoring logs.